# Turn off visibility of axis and grids in python plotly "go.Scatter3d"

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, plotly.graph-objects

```
import numpy as np
xx= np.array([[ 0,  0,  0], [ 0,  5,  0], [ 4,  5, -4], [ 4,  0,  0], [ 0,  0, -4], 
       [ 0,  5, -4],[ 4,  5,  0], [ 4,  0, -4], [ 8,  5, -4], [ 8,  0,  0], [ 8,  5,  0], 
       [ 8, 0, -4], [ 4, 10, -4], [ 4, 10,  0], [ 8, 10, -4], [ 8, 10,  0]])   
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(x=xx[:,2],y=xx[:,0],z=xx[:,1],mode='markers'))
fig.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLSPL.png)

Just want to see the points, removing all axis and gridlines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `scene` attribute as follows:

```
import numpy as np
xx= np.array([[ 0,  0,  0], [ 0,  5,  0], [ 4,  5, -4], [ 4,  0,  0], [ 0,  0, -4], 
       [ 0,  5, -4],[ 4,  5,  0], [ 4,  0, -4], [ 8,  5, -4], [ 8,  0,  0], [ 8,  5,  0], 
       [ 8, 0, -4], [ 4, 10, -4], [ 4, 10,  0], [ 8, 10, -4], [ 8, 10,  0]])   

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(x=xx[:,2],y=xx[:,0],z=xx[:,1],mode='markers'))
fig.update_layout(scene = dict(xaxis = dict(showgrid = False,showticklabels = False),
                                   yaxis = dict(showgrid = False,showticklabels = False),
                                   zaxis = dict(showgrid = False,showticklabels = False)
             ))
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You soo much, I was not using scene.